# To scrape the data from span tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the webpage, where I need to decode the entire table into a dataframe. I am using beautiful soup for this purpose. In certain `td` tags, there are `span` tags which do not have any text. But the values are shown on the webpage in that particular span tag.

The following `html` code corresponds to that webpage,

```
<td>
  <span class="nttu">::after</span>
  <span class="ntbb">::after</span>
  <span class="ntyc">::after</span>
  <span class="nttu">::after</span>
</td>
```

But, the value shown in this `td` tag is `23.8`. I tried to scrape it, but I am getting am empty text.

How to scrape this value using beautiful soup.

URL: https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/ws-432950.html

and my code is for **scraping** the table is given below,

```
http_url = "https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/01-2013/ws-432950.html"
retreived_data = requests.get(http_url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(retreived_data, "lxml")
climate_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "medias mensuales numspan"})
climate_data = climate_table.find_all("tr")
for data in climate_data[1:-2]:
  table_data = data.find_all("td")
  row_data = []
  for row in table_data:
    row_data.append(row.get_text())
  climate_df.loc[len(climate_df)] = row_data
```

Comment: page is likely dynamic and you'll need pull the html from the rendered page. Unless you share the url, not much any one will be able to help more with

Comment: @chitown88, I have added the URL of the site, in which you find an issue in 5th-row itself. Thanks

Comment: You might as well include you code, otherwise is very difficult to see what the problem is ;)

Comment: @ThananjayaS, are you just trying to pull that table?

Comment: @Isma, I have added the code for your reference, Thanks

Comment: @chitown88, I am just pulling the table and looping the 'tr' data. I have added the code for your reference. Thanks

Comment: why not just use pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Misunderstood your question as you have 2 different urls referenced. I see now what you mean.

Ya that is weird that in that second table, they used CSS to fill in the content of some of those `<td>` tags. What you need to do is pull out those special cases from the `<style>` tag. Once you have that, you can replace those elements within the html source, and finally parse it into a dataframe. I used pandas as it uses BeautifulSoup under the hood to parse `<table>` tags. But I believe this will get you what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

http_url = "https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/01-2013/ws-432950.html"
retreived_data = requests.get(http_url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(retreived_data, "lxml")

hiddenData = str(soup.find_all('style')[1])
hiddenSpan = {}
for group in re.findall(r'span\.(.+?)}',hiddenData):
    class_attr = group.split('span.')[-1].split('::')[0]
    content = group.split('"')[1]
    hiddenSpan[class_attr] = content

climate_table = str(soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "medias mensuales numspan"}))   
for k, v in hiddenSpan.items():
    climate_table = climate_table.replace('<span class="%s"></span>' %(k), hiddenSpan[k])


df = pd.read_html(climate_table)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                          Day                          T                         TM                         Tm                        SLP                          H                         PP                         VV                          V                         VM                         VG                         RA                         SN                         TS                         FG
0                           1                       23.4                       30.3                         19                          -                         59                          0                        6.3                        4.3                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
1                           2                       22.4                       30.3                       16.9                          -                         57                          0                        6.9                        3.3                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
2                           3                         24                       31.8                       16.9                          -                         51                          0                        6.9                        2.8                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
3                           4                       24.2                         32                       17.4                          -                         53                          0                          6                        3.3                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
4                           5                       23.8                         32                         18                          -                         58                          0                        6.9                        3.1                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
5                           6                       23.3                         31                       18.3                          -                         60                          0                        6.9                          5                        9.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
6                           7                       22.8                       30.2                       17.6                          -                         55                          0                        7.7                        3.7                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
7                           8                       23.1                       30.6                       17.4                          -                         46                          0                        6.9                        3.3                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
8                           9                       22.9                       30.6                       17.4                          -                         51                          0                        6.9                        3.5                        3.5                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
9                          10                       22.3                         30                         17                          -                         56                          0                        6.3                        3.3                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
10                         11                       22.3                       29.4                         17                          -                         53                          0                        6.9                        4.3                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
11                         12                       21.8                       29.4                       15.7                          -                         54                          0                        6.9                        2.8                        3.5                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
12                         13                       22.3                       30.1                       15.7                          -                         43                          0                        6.9                        2.8                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
13                         14                       21.8                       30.6                       14.8                          -                         41                          0                        6.9                        1.9                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
14                         15                       21.6                       30.6                       14.2                          -                         43                          0                        6.9                        3.1                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
15                         16                       21.1                       29.9                       15.4                          -                         55                          0                        6.9                        4.1                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
16                         17                       20.4                       28.1                       15.4                          -                         59                          0                        6.9                          5                       11.1                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
17                         18                       21.2                       28.3                       14.5                          -                         53                          0                        6.9                        3.1                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
18                         19                       21.6                       29.6                       16.4                          -                         58                          0                        6.9                        2.2                        3.5                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
19                         20                       21.9                       29.6                       16.6                          -                         58                          0                        6.9                        2.4                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
20                         21                       22.3                       29.9                       17.5                          -                         55                          0                        6.9                        3.1                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
21                         22                       21.9                       29.9                       15.1                          -                         46                          0                        6.9                        4.3                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
22                         23                       21.3                         29                       15.2                          -                         50                          0                        6.9                        3.3                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
23                         24                       21.3                       28.8                       14.6                          -                         45                          0                        6.9                          3                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
24                         25                       21.6                       29.1                       15.5                          -                         47                          0                        7.7                        4.8                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
25                         26                       21.8                       29.2                       14.6                          -                         41                          0                        6.9                        2.8                        3.5                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
26                         27                       22.3                       30.1                       15.6                          -                         40                          0                        6.9                        2.4                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
27                         28                       22.4                       30.3                         16                          -                         51                          0                        6.9                        2.8                        3.5                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
28                         29                         23                       30.3                       16.9                          -                         53                          0                        6.6                        2.8                        5.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                          o
29                         30                       23.1                         30                       17.8                          -                         54                          0                        6.9                        5.4                        7.6                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
30                         31                       22.1                       29.8                       17.3                          -                         54                          0                        6.9                        5.2                        9.4                          -                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN                        NaN
31  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:  Monthly means and totals:
32                        NaN                       22.3                         30                       16.4                          -                       51.6                          0                        6.9                        3.5                        6.3                        NaN                          0                          0                          0                          1
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted at first. But now I see. You used 2 different URLs in your question. I was looking at the first, which is the table I provided. But the code used and that what you are actually referring to is giving you the issue.

Comment: @Thananjaya S, I updated the code to answer your question. It wasn't originally clear given the 2 different urls references, but looking at it again I see what you meant.